# How to get orginal data back after it has been databound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I've databound some data to a datagrid and I'm wanting to be able to get the original data back.

I've databound the data as follows in one section of my code.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myClasses = GetMyClassesFromDatabase();
DataGridForMyClass.DataSource = myClasses;
DataGridForMyClass.DataBind();
```

When I've clicked a button, I want to be able to do stuff with the items in the datagrid.

How do I, given the DataGridForMyClass, retrieve the original list of MyClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pull it back out of the grid.  You will need to store the data somewhere (either `Session`, `Cache`, or `ViewState`) and retrieve it form there.  Only the basic controls and their values are stored in the grid.

For example if you are displaying a `DateTime` in a grid that uses a `Label`, the DateTime is not stored, just the text representation that was put and persisted via the `Label` is actually in the grid, your original bound data is not.

**EDIT:** From your comment, if you want to edit data in the grid then you have to post the data back and use the `RowCommand` or `RowUpdating` event.  See the following article:

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx

Comment: Then how do I persist the changes to those items, with a few modifications, back to the database?

Comment: @mezoid if this answer helped you don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.  If you need more help let me know.

Comment: I ended up parsing out the data from the user controls into a data transfer object and then using that object to retrieve the records from the database and update the details. While your answer doesn't exactly match what I did I guess it did point me in the direction of my chosen solution so I guess I can mark this one an answered.